# ASP eval is not translating correctly

Tags: asp.net

I have this piece of code and it is not evaluating correctly the `<%# Eval("url") %>` inside `OnClientClick`

```
<asp:LinkButton runat='server' Text='<%# Eval("Modulo") %>'
    OnClientClick='return LoadIframe(<%# Eval("url") %>)'
    ID='linkSeleccionar' />
```

because it is translating into:

```
<a onclick="return LoadIframe(&lt;%# Eval(&quot;url&quot;) %>);" id="RepMenu_RepModulos_0_linkSeleccionar_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$RepMenu$ctl01$RepModulos$ctl01$linkSeleccionar&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Hoja Trabajo</a>
```

How should it be written?

Answer (score 0):

try ,

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbtnEdit" Text='<%# Eval("Modulo") %>'
    OnClientClick='<%# "return LoadIframe(" + Eval("url") + ");" %>' />
```

or, You can bind it from code behind.

```
 protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            LinkButton button = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbtnEdit");
            string url= DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "url").ToString();

            button.OnClientClick = string.Format("return LoadIframe('{0}');", url);
            //button.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("return LoadIframe('{0}')", url));
        }
    }
```